# What is __libc_start_main and _start?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb, elf

From the past few days I have been trying to understand what happens behind the curtain when we execute a C program. However even after reading numerous posts I cannot find a detailed and accurate explanation for the same. Can someone please help me out ?

Comment: What is exactly the problem that needs to be answered?

Comment: @armagedescu I want to know in detail what happens before main() is executed in c. Also what is the role of __libc_start_main ?

Comment: Here's a great description of virtually everything that happens: http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html

Answer (score 16):

You would usually find special names like this for specific uses when compiling and linking programs.

Keeping in mind that this answer is of a general nature rather than a specific implementation of starting up a C environment, you would typically have something like a `_start` label, which would be the *actual* entry point for an executable (from the hosting environment's point of view).

This would be located in some object file or library (like [`crt0.o`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) for the C runtime start-up code) and would normally be added automagically to your executable file by the linker, similar to the way the C runtime library is added<sup>(a)</sup>.

The operating system code for starting a program would then be akin to (pseudo-code, obviously, and with *much* less error checking than it should have):

```py
def spawnProg(progName):
    id = newProcess()                       # make process space
    loadProgram(pid = id, file = progName)  # load program into it
    newThread(pid, initialPc = '_start')    # make thread to run it
```

Even though you yourself create a `main` when coding in C, that's not *really* where things start happening. There's a whole *slew* of things that need to be done even before your main program *starts*. Hence the content of the C start-up code would be along the lines of (at its most simplistic):

```
_start:  ;; Weave magic here to set up C and libc.
    ;; Note this is example code for a mythical implementation,
    ;; intended to show how it could work. It is not specific
    ;; bound to any given implementation.
    call __setup_for_c       ; Set up C environment.
    call __libc_start_main   ; Set up standard library.
    call _main               ; Call your main.
    call __libc_stop_main    ; Tear down standard library.
    call __teardown_for_c    ; Tear down C environment.
    jmp  __exit              ; Return to OS.
```

The "weaving of magic" is whatever it takes to make the environment ready for a C program. This *may* include things like:

- setting up static data (this is supposed to be initialised to zeros so it's probably just an allocation of a chunk of of memory, which is then zeroed by the start-up code - otherwise you would need to store a chunk of that size, already zeroed, in the executable file);
- preparing `argc` and `argv` on the stack, and even preparing the stack itself (there are specific calling conventions that may be used for C, and it's likely the operating system doesn't necessarily set up the stack *at all* when calling `_start` since the needs of the process are not known);
- setting up thread-specific data structures (things like random number generators, or error variables, per thread);
- initialising the C library in other ways; and so on.

Only once all that is complete will it be okay to call your `main` function. There's also the likelihood that work needs to be done *after* your `main` exits, such as:

- invoking `atexit` handlers (things you want run automatically on exit, no matter where the exit occurs);
- detaching from shared resources (for example, shared memory if the OS doesn't do this automatically when it shuts down a process); and
- freeing up any other resources not automatically cleaned when the process exits, that would otherwise hang around.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Many linkers can be told to *not* do that if, for example, you're writing something that doesn't use the standard C library, or if you want to provide your own `_start` routine for low-level work.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. However I am curious about "weaving of magic". Can you please explain how static data is setup and the remaining 3 things that you talked about ?

Comment: @perdix: how it's set up depends entirely on the environment, but I've added a couple of possibilities.

Comment: '80482e0:       31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp' Oh i get it. So if we consider the follow snippet of assembly code which I took from _start function. It is setting up static data right ? Because its xor of ebp with itself which would mean zero.

Comment: @perdix: `xor %ebp, %ebp` just zeroes a single register, which is in all likelihood the top level frame pointer before `main` is called. What you'd be looking for is a loop of some sort, such as https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/lk/+/qcom-dima-8x74-fixes/arch/x86/crt0.S starting line 232 with comment `Zero the memory in the .bss section`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!!

Comment: @paxdiablo could you have a look at this question plesase https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806608/does-start-call-my-programs-main-function-and-other-essential-setup-functions

Comment: That pseudo-code isn't how GCC/glibc does things: `_start` (in the executable itself) passes the address of `main` (not `_main`) to `__libc_start_main` (in libc.so.6); it calls libc startup/init functions and then calls main through that function pointer.  (If you single-step past the `ret` at the end of `main` in GDB, you'll find yourself just after an indirect `call` in glibc code, with `mov edi, eax` / `call exit` to run the normal atexit stuff before an `exit_group` system call to end all threads).  With those extra underscores on function names, perhaps you were thinking of MacOS?

Comment: @PeterCordes: I would have thought phrases like "typically", "akin to", and "along the lines of" would have made it abundantly clear I wasn't discussing a specific implementation but rather giving generalities:-) I'll make that clearer in the answer.

Comment: I didn't read the whole answer, I just came here after seeing [Does \_start call my program's main function and other essential setup functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63806608) quote this pseudo-code and ask why _start isn't calling anything else.  IDK if more of a caveat or comment right in the code block could warn people that these are things that happen somewhere, but not actually with code like that?

Comment: No probs, @PeterCordes, hopefully the changes (in both the answer proper and the comments in the code block) clarify this.