# What's the difference between `__libc_start_main` and `__libc_start_call_main`?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, elf

I recently learnt about the `__libc_start_main()` function. I thought that `__libc_start_main()` calls the `main()` function as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62709108/308909), but when I checked the stack pointer `$rsp` after inserting a breakpoint in the `main()` function in the test program below, it's the address of `__libc_start_call_main()`.

What's the difference between `__libc_start_main()` and `__libc_start_call_main()`?

##### Source code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    puts("Sunghyeon Lee");
}
```

##### gdb output

```
──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ gdb test   
GNU gdb (Debian 12.1-3) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from test...
(No debugging symbols found in test)
(gdb) b *main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1139
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/kali/test 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555139 in main ()
(gdb) x/a $rsp
0x7fffffffdec8: 0x7ffff7dd920a <__libc_start_call_main+122>
```

I searched for information about the difference between `__libc_start_main()` and `__libc_start_call_main()` but I haven't found an explanation.

Comment: [Here is the source code](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks! This is answer of my question.

Comment: By the way this is some function inside the C library - you shouldn't expect to find much information except for the C library source code itself, because nobody cares except for the C library developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have never found the explanation about it.

Take a look at the [commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;f=sysdeps/generic/libc_start_call_main.h;h=130fca173f323a24b41873b6656ab77c7cff86e1) which created `__libc_start_call_main`.

Effectively a chunk of `__libc_start_main` was split out into a separate routine.