# Is it true that on a Linux Ubuntu system the main function is called by the _libc_start_main function?

Tags: c, ubuntu, x86-64, program-entry-point, libc

My system : Ubuntu 22.04.3 running on x86_64 CPU.

I have this C program in a file named test.c :

```
int main(){

    long int a = 10;
    long int b = 20;
}
```

I've compiled the file with "gcc test.c -fno-stack-protector -mno-red-zone -o test" and then I executed "objdump -dw -M suffix test" ( I only show the _start function ) :

```
0000000000001040 <_start>:
    1040:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1044:   31 ed                   xorl   %ebp,%ebp
    1046:   49 89 d1                movq   %rdx,%r9
    1049:   5e                      popq   %rsi
    104a:   48 89 e2                movq   %rsp,%rdx
    104d:   48 83 e4 f0             andq   $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
    1051:   50                      pushq  %rax
    1052:   54                      pushq  %rsp
    1053:   45 31 c0                xorl   %r8d,%r8d
    1056:   31 c9                   xorl   %ecx,%ecx
    1058:   48 8d 3d ca 00 00 00    leaq   0xca(%rip),%rdi    # 1129 <main>
    105f:   ff 15 73 2f 00 00       callq  *0x2f73(%rip)   # 3fd8                                                           
                                                           <__libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.34>  
    1065:   f4                      hlt    
    1066:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00   cs nopw 0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

My assumption is that we have the following call chain within which _start calls __libc_start_main which in turn calls main :

_start -> __libc_start_main -> main

My question :

**Is the main function of my C program called by __libc_start_main in my specific Ubuntu system ?**

Comment: It seems like that. But why do you wonder about such very implementation-specific details? As an application developer the execution starts with the user-provided `main` function, anything before that is irrelevant.

Comment: It's not distro-specific, that's just how glibc does it on GNU/Linux systems.  So some of the startup code can be in libc.so instead of statically linked into each executable.  I'm surprised google didn't find more useful results with a specific function name to search on; `site:stackoverflow.com __libc_start_main` finds multiple highly-relevant questions.  Except that [What is \_\_libc\_start\_main and \_start?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62709030) is wrong, just a random guess at how things might work.  (See my comments on pax's answer.)

Answer (score 4):

> Is the main function of my C program called by __libc_start_main in my specific Ubuntu system?

Yes. It takes a pointer to your `main` function as an argument. That is, the type `int (*)(int, char **, char **)`.

This instruction uses instruction-pointer-relative addressing to refer to your `main` function, and puts the calculated result in the `rdi` register as an argument:

```
1058:   48 8d 3d ca 00 00 00    leaq   0xca(%rip),%rdi    # 1129 <main>
```

You may wonder, how is `main`'s address of `0x1129` calculated? You simply get the current value of the instruction pointer `0x1058`, add `0x7` (the length of the instruction itself), then the `0xCA` offset:

```
0x1058 + 0x7 + 0xCA = 0x1129
```

`libc_start_main` would then call your function indirectly through the contents of that register.